# No encuentro mi aplicacion en la playstore si la busco por el nombre, solamente por el package

Tags: android, google-play

Subí mí aplicación a la playstore, pero no la encuentro al buscarla por su nombre, solamente pueo hacerlo si la busco por el nombre del package.

Package: com.delreal.arthur.delrealapp

App Name: DelReal App

Si la busco por DelReal App, me tira una lista de 250 resultados, pero ninguna es mi aplicación.

Y si la busco por el nombre del package, sale inmediatamente.

Estube leyendo y me dice que utilize keywords en las descripciones. Ya lo hize y nada.

¿Alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me dijeron que era el certificado de clasificación, aunque desde ayer ya lo habia hecho. Incluso ya me llego la resolución del cuestionario de calsificación al correo.

Comment: Playstore se demora un poco cuando subes tu aplicación, pero si subiste tu aplicación para version Alpha o Beta, asegúrate que tu correo este dentro de los testers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente, era cuestión de tiempo. Han pasado 24 hrs desde que se subio la aplciación y se hizo la encuesta de tipo de contenido. Y ahora si ya es buscable la aplicación.